# to_numeric in python is rounding off the decimals

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I have the following:

```
test={'a': ['4.56','9.98','10.345']}
df=pd.DataFrame(test)
df

a
0   4.56
1   9.98
2   10.345
```

These are objects so I want to convert them to a float.

```
df['a']=pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')

    a
0   5
1   10
2   10
```

I get a float with the decimal rounded off. I want the full float:

```
0   4.56
1   9.98
2   10.345
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you format the question to properly indent the code?

Comment: Also, `df['a']` should be a float type. check `df.dtypes` after doing the `to_numeric` operation. Maybe your print is rounding it

Comment: Can you make this a single fully running script demonstrating the problem? I tried your code and got the desired result. If we can run the exact same code as you, it would help identify the problem.

Comment: The df is an object, not a float. I am converting the object to a float but its rounding

Comment: I thought that errors='coerce' would solve the problem but it doesn't

Comment: might help to say what version numbers you're using (e.g. Python, numpy and pandas).  have just tried with 3.11.5, 1.26.0 and 2.1.1 and everything works as expected.  might be worth simplify your example to: `pd.to_numeric(['4.56','9.98','10.345'])` as that should have the same semantics

Comment: I am using Python Pandas

Comment: Just want to add that this worked on Google Colab but I am using Jupyter Notebook. When I use Jupyter, it rounds it off.

Comment: I think I found the problem and its related to the memory. If I open a new python file in Jupyter, it works. But the one I am using is huge.

Comment: then you need to figure out which part of the file is causing issues!  it also helps to quantify "huge", e.g. millions of rows, billions?  doing a binary search to find the first row that causes an issue in the billions of rows case is less than 40 iterations.